# How to make effect of sand blowing away revealing a buried object?

Tags: texturing, particles, smoke-simulation

I'm pretty new to Blender and 3D modeling/animation in general so apologies in advance if this is stupid.
I'm trying to create the effect of an object (A sign in this case, so a flat plane) that's buried in sand, just under the surface.. and then wind blows the top layer of sand away, revealing the sign.
I'm probably going to use a mixture of a particle system and smoke for the sand in the wind, the issue I'm facing is the layer of sand covering the sign that's then blown out of the way to reveal it. Any ideas how I could do this? Without just using a particle system and having a million tiny particles that'll take forever to render.
I was thinking of maybe mixing a musgrave texture of the sand texture on the plane, and animating the scale, position and strength of the mix so it sort of... moves and fades away? But I'm not quite sure how to make it look realistic.
Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Give a boolean to the sand object, create another object that will be the boolean object (here, a cube), use a *Displace* modifier for this boolean object so that its surface evolves through time, add an object that will emit the sand particles:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 @moonboots, this is great! Could you share your blend-file with us?

Comment: sure, I've edited my answer